# pi camera will not work with Pi zero

Tags: pi-zero, gpiozero

My Pi camera will not work with the Pi zero using the same python code I use on my Pi 3 or Pi 2
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Yes, since it's not working you're certainly missing something. It's really hard to tell what you're missing exactly, since your question has so little information in it.

Comment: Back to basics...check that the camera interface has been enabled.

Comment: What did the terminal print?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have inserted it correctly and enable the Camera Module in the Interfaces tab of Raspberry Pi configuration

Answer (score 1):

Open the cmd and type this command

**vcgencmd get_camera**

you should get this output

**supported=1 detected=1**

otherwise, the camera is not mounted properly. Unplug and plug the camera again.

Try this command.

**raspistill -o image.jpg**

This will take a new picture and store it in the current directory.